# Modify text size in Shiny

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, shiny

I'm a beginner on Shiny, and I'd like to modify the text size, but it doesn't really work :

```
h1(strong("TITLE"), align="center", style = "font-family: 'Times', serif;
    font-weight: 500; font-size: 500; text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #aaa; line-height: 1; 
     color: #404040;"),
```

Color, font-family and text-shadow is working, but not the other ones... Do you know how to change the size and the thickness of my title please ?

Answer (score 11):

I think you are missing a couple of "px" inside the style arguments. It should read

```
h1(strong("Title"), style = "font-size:500px;")
```

Tha same goes for the rest styling options.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answers. Now I can modify the size, but not the thickness. Even the `strong`parameter is not working : `h1(strong("TITLE"), align="center", style = "font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
        font-weight: normal; font-thickness: 500%; font-size: 500%; text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #aaa; line-height: 0.4; 
         color: #404040;")`

Comment: @Niamor `font-thickness` is an unknown CSS property.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent So it is impossible to change the thickness of a text in Shiny ? With `font-family: Cinzel, serif` , even `strong()` on my character isn't working.

Comment: No problem when I try them. You can go to the localhost shiny deployment and inspect the text you have added with Right Click -> Inspect (Ctrl+Shift+I), maybe there is a shiny css file that overwrites your styling options.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried using a function other than h1? Shiny uses the following to functions to call html5 functions:

[image]

[Link to shiny documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson2/)

Is this what you need?

Comment: I've got the same problem with div : font-thickness or font-weight are not working.